# i.i.d. random variables' questions.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[image]

Hi I was wondering if anyone could advise me on this question.

So from previous assistance, I have learned that I should be focusing on the equation:

$P(Y>1)=1-P(Y\leq1)$ so that it suffices to compute $P(Y\leq1)$

and hence use:

$P(Y\leq1)=P(x_1\leq1,X_2\leq1,X_3\leq1)$ $=P(X_1\leq1)P(X_2\leq1)P(X_3\leq1)$

and I have been shown that $P(X_i\leq1)=F(1)$ for each $i$

So from this I was wondering if this means to substitute $x=1$ into the equation of $F(x)$ which gives me the value 3. And if I'm going off the advice I have been given this should mean that:

$P(Y\leq1)=3*3*3$ which I just don't think can be correct.

I think I may be misinterpreting the information. Can someone please advise me on where I'm going wrong and how to actually approach this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @K.defaoite What makes you say it's not a CDF?

Comment: It is not a PDF since it doesn't integrate to 1 @K.defaoite

Comment: Usually the shorthand "distribution function" indicates a PDF, not a CDF. My mistake.

Comment: @K.defaoite The CDF is the one that is guaranteed to exist. PDFs only exist for the nicest random variables. In my opinion it would make more sense to usually indicate the other way.

Answer (score 1):

Minor mistake: $F(1)=1-2^{-1}=1-1/2=1/2$.

Comment: Thank you! Very silly mistake on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Inputting $x=1$ in $F(x)=1-2^{-x}$ does not give you $3$. It gives you
$$
1-2^{-1}=1-\frac12=\frac12
$$
Apart from that, your answer seems perfectly fine.

Comment: Ah okay thank you! Such a stupid mistake on my behalf. So I assume from here I use the fact that $P(Y\leq1)=(0.5*0.5*0.5)$ and then use the fact that $P(Y>1)=1-P(Y\leq1)$ and state that $P(Y>1)=0.875$

Comment: @TaylorS. Exactly! And "to 3 d.p." even gives you the exact answer.